# Downloading files generated by Google Apps Script (Sheets) via ruby

Tags: ruby, google-sheets, google-apps-script

Consider the following Apps Script that generates json files based on each tab in a Google Sheet:

```
function makeJSON() {
  var spreadsheetId = 'someId';
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  var sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();
  var urls = []; // Array to store the URLs of the created files

  for (var i =  1; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    var sheet = sheets[i];
    var data = sheet.getRange(3,  1, sheet.getLastRow() -  2, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    var headers = sheet.getRange(2,  1,  1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];

    var objects = data.map(function(row) {
    var obj = {};
    for (var j =  0; j < headers.length; j++) {
      //process data in the sheets
    return obj;
    });


    var json = JSON.stringify(objects, null,  2);

// Create a blob from the JSON string
var blob = Utilities.newBlob(json, 'application/json', sheet.getName() + '.json');

 var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('someId');
 var file = folder.createFile(blob);

 file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
 urls.push(file.getUrl());
  }
}

function doGet() {
  var urls = makeJSON(); // Call the function to generate JSON files and get their URLs
  Logger.log(urls) //this logs all the files correctly
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({urls: urls})).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);

}
```

It works fine when I download all the json files to Google Drive with `folder.createFile(blob);` But I'm trying to this with a ruby script so that I don't have to manually run the script and download the files. So I deployed it as a web app (public permissions) and put that into `web_app_url` below. Here's the `.rb` file:

```
 require 'typhoeus'
require 'json'

web_app_url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/digits/exec'
download_directory = './downloads'

# Make an HTTP GET request to trigger the Web App
response = Typhoeus.get(web_app_url, followlocation: true)

if response.success?
  json_response = JSON.parse(response.body)
  json_urls = json_response['urls']

  # Download each file to the specified directory
  json_urls.each do |url|
    file_name = File.basename(url)
    download_path = File.join(download_directory, file_name)

    # Use open-uri to open the URL and download the file
    require 'open-uri'
    open(url, 'rb') do |file|
      File.open(download_path, 'wb') do |local_file|
        local_file.write(file.read)
      end
    end
    puts "Downloaded #{file_name} to #{download_directory}"
  end
else
  puts "HTTP status code: #{response.code}"
  puts "Response body: #{response.body}"
  puts "Failed to fetch URLs: #{response.status_message}"
end
```

But I get this error:

```
    warning: calling URI.open via Kernel#open is deprecated, call URI.open directly or use URI#open
Traceback (most recent call last):
    9: from download.rb:15:in `<main>'
    8: from download.rb:15:in `each'
    7: from download.rb:21:in `block in <main>'
    6: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/open-uri.rb:19:in `open'
    5: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/open-uri.rb:50:in `open'
    4: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/open-uri.rb:744:in `open'
    3: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/open-uri.rb:178:in `open_uri'
    2: from download.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    1: from download.rb:22:in `open'
download.rb:22:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - ./downloads/view?usp=drivesdk (Errno::ENOENT)
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong? And how do I specify where on my machine these files get downloaded to?

Comment: You can download files with FileZilla pro

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your showing Google Apps Script and Ruby script. From your showing ruby script, are you using `doGet` function? If my understanding is correct, Can you provide your whole script of Google Apps Script to correctly understand your current situation? Also, can I ask you about the setting of your Web Apps? What are the values of `Execute as:` and `Who has access to the app:`? And, is your account in Google Workspace? First, I would like to correctly understand your situation.

Comment: @Tanaike sorry about that. I updated the post. The `Execute as:` is set to me, and `Who has access to the app:` is set to Anyone.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Your currently showing script is your actual script. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: yes, aside from the `//process data in the sheets` which isn't relevant here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your showing script, when I believe `Logger.log(urls) //this logs all the files correctly`, I guessed that the reason for your current issue might be due to `getUrl()` of `urls.push(file.getUrl());`. In the case of `getUrl()`, the URL is like `https://drive.google.com/file/d/${fileId}/view?usp=drivesdk`. This link is not the direct link to the file. I guessed that this might be the reason for your current issue. If my guess was correct, how about the following modification?

In this modification, your Ruby side is modified.

#### From:

```
json_urls.each do |url|
  file_name = File.basename(url)
```

#### To:

```
json_urls.each do |url|
  id = url.split("/")[5]
  url = "https://drive.usercontent.google.com/download?confirm=xxx&id=#{id}" # This is from https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/f0f2d122e05bf5f971611258c22c110f
  file_name = File.basename(url)
```

- By this modification, the URL of `https://drive.google.com/file/d/${fileId}/view?usp=drivesdk` is converted to `https://drive.usercontent.google.com/download?confirm=xxx&id={fileId}`. By using a sample URL `https://drive.google.com/file/d/${fileId}/view?usp=drivesdk`, when I tested this modification, I confirmed that a file could be correctly downloaded.

#### Note:

The modified whole script is as follows.

```rb
require 'typhoeus'
require 'json'

web_app_url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/{deploymentId}/exec'
download_directory = './downloads'

# Make an HTTP GET request to trigger the Web App
response = Typhoeus.get(web_app_url, followlocation: true)

if response.success?
  json_response = JSON.parse(response.body)
  json_urls = json_response['urls']

  # Download each file to the specified directory
  json_urls.each do |url|
    id = url.split("/")[5]
    url = "https://drive.usercontent.google.com/download?confirm=xxx&id=#{id}"
    file_name = File.basename(url)
    download_path = File.join(download_directory, file_name)

    # Use open-uri to open the URL and download the file
    require 'open-uri'
    open(url, 'rb') do |file|
      File.open(download_path, 'wb') do |local_file|
        local_file.write(file.read)
      end
    end
    puts "Downloaded #{file_name} to #{download_directory}"
  end
else
  puts "HTTP status code: #{response.code}"
  puts "Response body: #{response.body}"
  puts "Failed to fetch URLs: #{response.status_message}"
end
```

#### Note:

- In this answer, it is supposed as follows. Please be careful about this.

  - The values `urls` of `var urls = makeJSON();` are valid valuers.
  - All files of URLs are publicly shared.
  - The values `json_urls` at Ruby side are valid values.
  - The URL is `https://drive.google.com/file/d/${fileId}/view?usp=drivesdk`.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. I have a follow up question about google drive file deletion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78056953/permission-issues-deleting-files-with-google-drive-api-in-ruby

Comment: @soleil Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, I answered it.